# How can I add syntax highlighting to a make error message?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cmake, pipeline

## Summary

I want to manually add syntax highlighting of specific words in error messages. I tried with a pipeline to `awk`, but this doesn't seem to work with the entire message that is thrown by `make`. Can anybody help me to get the following pipeline working for `make`'s entire error message?

```
make | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/error/ || $i~/Built/) $i=sprintf("\033[0;36m %s \033[0;00m",$i)}; print}'
```

Or maybe—better still—a different approach to my

### Situation (in detail)

To build my latex project, I use Cmake together with UseLATEX ([github page](https://gitlab.kitware.com/kmorel/UseLATEX)). That way, I can simply render my document by executing `make` from inside a build folder. Only problem: There is no syntax highlighting for the wall of text of an error message. I need to add a minimal version of this, to work productively. (Maybe words could be highlighted globally in my terminal?)

By passing the output in a pipeline to `awk` ([manpage](https://man.cx/awk))—inspired by [this askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/755535/how-do-i-highlight-a-word-or-a-phrase-in-a-commands-output)—I was able to highlight `make`'s success message, `pdflatex myfile.tex`'s success **and error** message, but *not* `make`'s error message, it did not highlight the interesting parts of the long message.

By highlighting `Built` in the code snippet above, one can see that it does highlight when the first command `make` succeeds.

The problem is that I do not fully understand when the pipeline passes what. It seems that some output can get highlighted and some cannot.

Thanks for any help!

### Steps needed to reproduce

To get into *exactly* the situation at hand, you need a project folder containing

```
build/
cmake/
myfile.tex
CMakeLists.txt
```

with `cmake/` containing [`UseLATEX.cmake`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/kmorel/UseLATEX/-/blob/master/UseLATEX.cmake)
and `CMakeLists.txt` reading

```
include(cmake/UseLATEX.cmake)

ADD_LATEX_DOCUMENT(myfile.tex)
```

and `myfile.tex` being a valid or non-valid latex document, e.g.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
    Some \undefined command
  \end{document}
```

From inside the `build/` folder, call `cmake ..`, and then `make`, or rather the full command above.

Comment: Use IDE. One of great features of IDE is highlighting error messages, or even jumping to a flie to a line to specific column where the error is. `It seems that some output can get highlighted and some cannot.` Read about "standard POSIX streams" and about stderr and stdout. Most probably the message is written on stderr. Please try `make 2>&1 | awk ....`

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk, that fixed it. That was quick! What do I do, edit the question, prepend [SOLVED]? I'm all new, so happy about hints. And the `2>&1` command, while you're at it: What does it do? :)

Comment: @KamilCuk IDE works well in most cases. It is only not an option if an automatized processing is needed (CI/CD, build pipelines).

Comment: `What does it do?` Read good bash introduction, research redirections in shell. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055

Comment: Yeah, you quenched my most urgent thirst for understanding in your answer, but thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is written on stderr, not on stdout. You have to handle stderr. In bash, you can:

```
make 2> >(do_something_with_stderr >&2) | do_something_with_stdout
```

Because `|` changes buffering, it's not always wanted in interactive programs. For  interactive I prefer:

```
make 2> >(do_something_with_stderr >&2) >(do_something_with_stdout)
```

and sometimes that's one function:

```
some_func() { do_something; }
make 2> >(some_func >&2) >(some_func)
```